# How to migrate from VSS to VSTS?

Tags: migration, azure-devops, visual-sourcesafe

I am working on migration, now I have some projects in Visual SourceSafe but I want to migrate them into VSTS. I got solution VSS-TFS, but I need direct way to migrate. So, can you give me the simpliest way to migrate them from VSS to VSTS

Comment: Please read [ask] and accept that you are expected to do a decent amount of research before posting here. Very likely there's enough documentation online if you bothered to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t migrate from VSS to VSTS directly, currently, the supported TFS versions are TFS 2017 update 1 and update 2.

[Supported TFS Versions for Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview#supported-tfs-versions-for-import)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes we can do it from VSS to TFS and then TFS to VSTS. For that I need to install the VSS update 2005 with converter, but I am getting this Error message "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program.Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch." while installing. Can you give me solution for this

Comment: Yes, I have already posted the above issue in the following link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585052/how-to-install-vss-in-windows-10-pc

Comment: What's the detail version of your VSS and what's your OS? Are there any update records in control panel?

Comment: The version of my VSS is 1.0. I am using Windows 10PC and I don't have any update records in control panel

Comment: Check this: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28925152/Installation-of-Visual-Source-Safe-2005-on-Win-10-machine-fails.html

Comment: No, It's not solved. I think somewhere has need to do

Comment: Actually you can migrate VSS directly to VSTS. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you **can** migrate your VSS database directly to VSTS (now Azure DevOps) using [Visual Source Safe Upgrade Tool for Team Foundation Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdH-MSFT.VisualSourceSafeUpgradeToolforTeamFoundationServer)

I have done it just now (time of posting) migrated a project created in Visual SourceSafe 2005 directly to a TFVC team project in VSTS using this tool. I used this fine and detailed [guide](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2018/04/visual-source-safe-vss-to-tfs-migration.html). In step two of the Upgrade Wizard, instead of browsing to a team project in TFS, just connect to your VSTS and pick a team project as target destination.