# How to install VSS in Windows 2007

Tags: windows-7, visual-sourcesafe

I am working on Visual SourceSafe, for that I am trying to install the VSS update 2005. At the time of installing I am getting the following Error message: "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program.Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."
Can you give me the solution for the above issue and I downloaded it from the following [enter link description here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=291)